# rsync only the latest modified of a file type

Tags: rsync, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is this possible to achieve? I have a directory to be synced, and it contains few subfolders, they consists of various file of different types. I'm interested in only the latest modified file of a type (let's say `*.txt`) in the directory including the subfolders, and any subfolders inside it. Any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

check rsync manual page `man rsync`:

```
--ignore-existing       skip updating files that exist on receiver
```

By using `--ignore-existing` you can ignore files which are already exist on remote and copy the files which are created new on source system.
There are various [rsync example](https://linuxconcept.com/rsync-example-for-system-administrator/) to use daily administrative life.